# react-cookie - Cookies not being removed/deleted

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I have been trying various syntax for react-cookie but not matter what, the cookies are not deleted.

Here is relevant code:

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
....
....
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookieName', 'cookieDob']);
....

removeCookie(['cookieName','cookieDob'],{path:'/'});
router.push(`/user/`+userId);
```

Comment: The documentation says that you have to type the cookie name as `string` instead of `array` like this `removeCookie('cookieName',{path:'/'});`

Comment: So one removeCookie line for each cookie? I have 15 cookies.

Comment: Yes, that's what their documentation says. If you want to remove all cookies, you can simply read all cookies using `getAll` method and loop through array and remove them.